# How to use the node distance to offset the start and/or end of an arrow with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows

I want to draw an arrow where one of the end points is not actually attached to another node, and I want the length of the arrow to take into account the node distance of the node to which the arrow *is* attached. So I would like to be able to write something like

```
\draw [->] ([left of] the-node) -- (the-node);
```

See the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node/.style={
      node distance=5mm,
    },
  ]
  \node [node] (n) {n};

  % This is what I would like to write (or something like it)
  %\draw [->] ([left of] n) -- (n);

  % Here are my options so far, none of which I like

  % 1:
  \draw [->] ([yshift=5mm] n.north) -- (n);
  % CON: requires explicit use of the node distance

  % 2:
  \coordinate (coord1) at ([xshift=5mm] n.east);
  \draw [->] (coord1) -- (n);
  % CON: requires explicit use of the node distance AND an extra coordinate

  % 3:
  \coordinate [below=of n] (coord2);
  \draw [->] (coord2) -- (n);
  % CON: requires an extra coordinate, and it doesn't seem to use the node
  % distance of 'n' anyway
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result of the MWE:

[image]

Any ideas of how I could achieve this?

Comment: Does the post [make-stealth-horizontal-in-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144358/make-stealth-horizontal-in-tikz) help?

Comment: Not really. First, it assumes the existance of two nodes between which to draw the arrow (in my case, there is only a single node). Second, the solution entails the creation of an auxiliary node which is one of the options I did not like. I would like to be able to get away it not having to create any additional nodes or coordinates (if possible).

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. The easiest way would be to define an extra macro `\def\DIST{5mm}` and use that instead of manually writing `5mm` everywhere, e.g. `node distance=\DIST` and `yshift=\DIST` or `\draw (node.north) ++(0,\DIST) -- (node);`.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, the `node distance` is not saved with the node. If you want to specify the distance on a per-node basis, you'd probably have to define a custom key in order to save additional data alongside the node itself.

Comment: I don't know how to improve it so it's just a comment but `\begin{scope}[node distance=2cm] \makeatletter \draw [->]  (n) --++(90:\tikz@node@distance); \makeatother \end{scope}` worked for me.

Comment: @Fritz: Yeah, using a custom macro is always a solution to avoid repetition, but I figured TikZ being what it is it might have some more clever way of doing it. =)

Comment: @Ignasi: Actually, it's along the lines that I thought of myself. Can you please write it as an answer so that I can vote on it? =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use relative coordinates on the left side.  (On the right side you have to use calc.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n) {n};
  \draw [->] (n.north)+(0,5mm) -- (n);
  \draw [->] (n.east)+(5mm,0) -- (n);
  \draw [->] (n.south)+(0,-5mm) -- (n);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

An even simpler solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n) {n};
  \draw [<-] (n.north) -- +(0,5mm);
  \draw [<-] (n.east) -- +(5mm,0);
  \draw [<-] (n.south) -- +(0,-5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, at least you don't need an auxiliary coordinate, but you still need to add the node distance explicitly. Still, it's better than what I've tried. =)

Comment: The "node distance" as I understand it is the point where the arrow stops.  It you both start and stop it at the same point...  Now if you want to create a new node type that draws arrows from the borders to the text area, that can be done.  Look up \pgfdeclareshape.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you could do the calculation on both sides?

Comment: @Joost - TikZ puts the text inside a savebox named \pgfnodeparttextbox which can provide you with the width and height.  One can extract the x,y coordinates for the anchors using saved anchors (normally only \northeast and \southwest are used).

Comment: If anyone's curious what "on the right side you have to use calc" means specifically: [the documentation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.5) has some useful examples. **tl;dr**: `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in the preamble and then say `\draw [->] (n.north)+(0,5mm) -- ($(n.south)+(0,7mm)$);` in your tikz (for example)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution (that shows how to use `node distance`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n) {n};
  \begin{scope}[node distance=2cm]
    \draw[red,->] coordinate[below=of n] (a) (a) -- (n);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[node distance=1cm]
    \draw[blue,->] coordinate[left=of n] (a) (a) -- (n);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[node distance=5mm]
    \draw[green,->] coordinate[right=of n] (a) (a) -- (n);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's interesting. So what's going on here? Within the `\draw`, you declare a coordinate `a` that's placed relatively from `n`, and then you refer to `a` right afterwards? Didn't know you could do that. But what I meant was to use the `node distance` of `n`, without having to explicitly declare it again.

Comment: @gablin The `node distance` is not a property attached to a node. It is a global value (eventually scoped) used when you position (via `positioning` library) a new node.

Answer (score 2):

### Standard scoped distance values

The `node distance` setting is not an attribute of a node, but of the surrounding scope. So you can't access *"the node distance of `n`"* as you put it, but only *"the current node distance"*. Using this, you can define a style which uses the current node distance as an offset, as in:

```
my above/.style={yshift=\tikz@node@distance},
```

Now you can use coordinates of the form `([my above] n.center)`. Unfortunately, specifying a node anchor is necessary, because otherwise TikZ will try to calculate a point on the border of the node, ignoring the `yshift` option in the process.

[image: Use current node distance]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
\node[node distance=20mm] (n) {n}; % node distance does nothing here
\draw[->,red]   ([my above=n] n.center) -- (n);
\draw[->,green] ([my below]n.center) -- (n);
\draw[->,blue]   ([my left]n.center) -- (n);

% Larger node distance for the right line
\begin{scope}[node distance=10mm]
    \draw[->,purple] ([my right]n.center) -- (n);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

### Per-Node distance values

Now, if you want to store an attribute on a per-node basis, you have to define a global macro whose name contains the node name (stored in `\tikz@fig@name`), which contains the desired value:

```
my distance/.style={execute at end node={%
        \expandafter\gdef\csname my@node@distance@\tikz@fig@name\endcsname{#1}%
}},
```

This is what the `my distance` style does: it defines a macro called `\my@node@distance@NAME` where `NAME` is the name of the currently declared node. This macro contains the value assigned in `my distance=10mm`, which can then be accessed later using the previously mentioned name, as shown in the `my above2` style:

```
my above2/.style={yshift/.expanded=\csname my@node@distance@#1\endcsname },
```

The only drawback is that you have to specify the node name again as an argument, as in `([my above2=n] n.center)`, because the name of the node has not been parsed yet when processing the options. So we need the extra argument in order to tell it to use the stored distance of the node `n`, and not some other node.

Note that the purple arrow is not affected by the node distance set on the `scope` and still uses the value of `my distance=10mm`, which was specified when defining the node `n`.

[image: Using per-node distance]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
\node[my distance=10mm] (n) {n};
\draw[->,red]   ([my above2=n] n.center) -- (n);
\draw[->,green] ([my below2=n] n.center) -- (n);
\draw[->,blue]   ([my left2=n] n.center) -- (n);

% This method is completely unaffected by setting node distance
\begin{scope}[node distance=20mm]
    \draw[->,purple] ([my right2=n]n.center) -- (n);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

### The complete code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter
% Basic solution using the current node distance
\tikzset{
    my above/.style={yshift=\tikz@node@distance},
    my below/.style={yshift=-\tikz@node@distance},
    my right/.style={xshift=\tikz@node@distance},
    my left/.style={xshift=-\tikz@node@distance},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
\node[node distance=20mm] (n) {n}; % node distance does nothing here
\draw[->,red]   ([my above=n] n.center) -- (n);
\draw[->,green] ([my below]n.center) -- (n);
\draw[->,blue]   ([my left]n.center) -- (n);

% Larger node distance for the right line
\begin{scope}[node distance=10mm]
    \draw[->,purple] ([my right]n.center) -- (n);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

% Advanced solution using per-node storage
\tikzset{
    my above2/.style={yshift/.expanded=\csname my@node@distance@#1\endcsname },
    my below2/.style={yshift/.expanded=-\csname my@node@distance@#1\endcsname},
    my right2/.style={xshift/.expanded=\csname my@node@distance@#1\endcsname },
    my left2/.style= {xshift/.expanded=-\csname my@node@distance@#1\endcsname},
    my distance/.style={
        execute at end node={%
            \expandafter\gdef\csname my@node@distance@\tikz@fig@name\endcsname{#1}%
        }%
    },
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
\node[my distance=10mm] (n) {n};
\draw[->,red]   ([my above2=n] n.center) -- (n);
\draw[->,green] ([my below2=n] n.center) -- (n);
\draw[->,blue]   ([my left2=n] n.center) -- (n);

% This method is completely unaffected by setting node distance
\begin{scope}[node distance=20mm]
    \draw[->,purple] ([my right2=n]n.center) -- (n);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are probably better ways of using `\tikz@node@distance` without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` but I don't know them, so I'm open to any suggestion.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n) {n};

  \makeatletter
  \begin{scope}[node distance=2cm]
   \draw [->, red]  (n) --++(90:\tikz@node@distance);
   \begin{scope}[node distance=1cm]
   \draw [->, blue]  (n) --++(0:\tikz@node@distance);
   \draw [->, orange]  (n) --++(180:\tikz@node@distance);
   \end{scope}
   \draw [->, green]  (n) --++(-90:\tikz@node@distance);
  \end{scope}
   \makeatother

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:* Next code shows one of percusse's suggestions:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\def\nodedistance{\tikz@node@distance}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n) {n};

  \begin{scope}[node distance=2cm]
   \draw [->, red]  (n) --++(90:\nodedistance);
   \begin{scope}[node distance=1cm]
   \draw [->, blue]  (n) --++(0:\nodedistance);
   \draw [->, orange]  (n) --++(180:\nodedistance);
   \end{scope}
   \draw [->, green]  (n) --++(-90:\nodedistance);
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can always `\let` it or `\def` ine it to a non-`@` macro and use that as an alias.

Comment: @percusse: Thank you. I've applied one of your suggestions. Please, feel free to edit it if something is wrong.